# Run js command with Symfony's Component Process

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, npm, symfony-process

I want to run npm-like commands with Symfony's Component Process. The actual command is `relaxed htmlFile.html`. The command works when I run it with CLI, but when I run it with Process I get the error below.

```
The command "node -v" failed. Exit Code: 1(General error) Working directory: C:\xampp\pro-resume\public Output: ================ Error Output: ================ 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I'm using a library called [relaxed.js](https://github.com/RelaxedJS/ReLaXed) to convert HTML files to PDF.

In this example, I tried to run `node -v`.

```
$process = new Process(['node', '-v']);
$process->mustRun();
echo $process->getOutput();

if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
   throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}
```

The env is Xampp server on Windows. Laravel 9, php 8.

Comment: Looks like Node isn't installed globally, try in terminal `which node` to get the path then add it, for example `new Process(['/usr/path/node', '-v'])`.  Or make Node global..

Comment: You can also use the `$process->setWorkingDirectory('/you_dir');` method to set the working directory where your commands will be executed

Comment: @HarveyDent thanks, I'll try setting the directory, seems like it is looking for node in the public directory.

Comment: @HarveyDent not sure where should I set the working directory, currently it's public, but where should I run node?